# I need advice with my password generator python script

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I need help with my code. I wrote a script that generates a password. However, when I added 'while-loop' it doesn't seem to work well. The code worked without 'while-loop'.
Additionally, I was thinking to store the password that was generated into a database, like SQLite. Here is the code:
Thanks!

```
import random
import string


let = string.ascii_letters
num = string.digits
pun = string.punctuation



while True:
    name = str(input('Enter Yes to initiate | type END to exit: ').lower())

    if name == 'end':
        print('Thanks!')
        break

    else:
        if name == 'yes':

            def get_passcode_lenght():
                length = input("How long do you want your password? ")
                return int(length)

            def passcode_generator(cbl,length=4):
                showpass = user_choice_combo(cbl)
                showpass = list(showpass)
                random.shuffle(showpass)

                random_passcode = random.choices(showpass, k=length)
                random_passcode = ''.join(random_passcode)
                return random_passcode

            def passcode_combo_choice():

                digits = (input("Do you want digits? | Yes or No: ")).lower()
                letters = (input("Do you want letters? | Yes or No: ")).lower()
                puncts = (input("Do you want punctuations? | Yes or No: ")).lower()
                Yes = True
                No = False

                try:
                    digits = eval(digits.title())
                    letters = eval(letters.title())
                    puncts = eval(puncts.title())
                    return [digits, letters, puncts]
                except NameError:
                    print("Invalid value. Use either Yes or No")
                    print("Invalidity returns a default, try again to regenerate")
                return [Yes, Yes, Yes]

            def user_choice_combo(choice_list):
                string_constant = ''
                string_constant += num if choice_list[0] else ''
                string_constant += let if choice_list[1] else ''
                string_constant += pun if choice_list[2] else ''
                return string_constant


if __name__ == '__main__':
    length = get_passcode_lenght()
    choice_list = passcode_combo_choice()
    password = passcode_generator(choice_list, length)
    print(password)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused about function definition vs function usage. `def my_fun` defines a function so that you can later use it. To execute that function you'll need to call it with `my_fun()`. So your code should look more like this:

```
def get_passcode_length():
    ....

....
if name == 'yes':
    get_passcode_length()
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was very helpful!!

Comment: Glad to hear it. If it solved your problem, please accept the answer so the question will be closed.